# Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'xxx'

Tags: c#, database, connection

When I am running the application I am getting the following configuration error:

> Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'kubota1'

Here is the connection string:

```
string connectionString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=kubota1;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I have already created a database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the password value in your connection string. For now, it is missed.

Answer (score 0):

are you able to connect database directly from MySQL workbench?
if yes, then open Visual Studio > View > Server Explorer > Connect to Database.
Enter required credentials and connect. If it is connected from Visual Studio then select database from Server Explorer >> Right Click >> Properties.

From there you can copy connection string and use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on database Collation type, it was latin1_swedish_ci  and I changed it to utf8_general_ci